# Publish ASP.NET Core MVC website to IONOS 1&1 via Visual Studio FTP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, ftp, web-hosting

I know this is vague and might get shut down, but it's really rather important!
I have a C# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC app with a MSSQL database that I want to publish to an IONOS 1&1 hosting service. I've tried using the Publish menu in Visual Studio 2019 via FTP, put in my credentials and then another box pops up asking me to put in my FTP password again, I type it in and it says I'm not authorised. Checked password and username carefully, these are fine. I'm not finding it very user friendly AT ALL! Azure is a million times easier but also about 10 times more expensive so I want to use IONOS! Please help.... or guide me to a step by step solution or something..... heeeeelp!

Answer (score 12):

OK - I've finally figured it out! In Visual Studio > Build > Publish...

Publish method: FTP
Server: The server provided by IONOS (you can get this by downloading the FileZilla configuration file and then copy and paste the server name across)
Site path: LEAVE THIS BLANK - THIS IS WHAT WAS CAUSING ALL THE PROBLEMS!!!
Enable passive mode
Username: Hopefully you know this!
Password: Hopefully you know this!
Destination URL: e.g. http://chickensoup.com/

Then it should work! Make sure you have an SSL certificate otherwise the webpage will give a security error and not show.